# Mail.app: How can I set a different default signature for each address?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have my Gmail account setup in Mail 6.2 (Mountain Lion). From that account I can send mail with one of five different addresses (4 other accounts forwarding onto Gmail). Is there a way I can set up a different default signature for each address, rather than a single default signature for all addresses?

I have 5 addresses and 5 signatures, I just can't link them together.

Answer (score 1):

1) Open Settings (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>), click signatures. You will see a list of email accounts on the right.

[image: Signatures]

2) **Click the one you want to set a default signature to. Click the + button below the signatures.**

[image: + and - buttons below signatures]

3) **Add you signature.**

If you have more than one signature, select your preferred default on from the drop down menu below the signatures.

[image: Default signature]

Comment: Thanks @bassplayer7, however this sets the default signature for the entire Gmail account. As I mentioned I have multiple addresses within that account, and would like a different default signature for **each** address.

Comment: I am sorry - I obviously hadn't understood your question. I've never had a setup similar to yours, but am guessing that there would be no way to do that. The signature making, and assigning, process that I described seems about as much customization as is available in the current UI.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try [SignatureProfiler](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23037/signatureprofiler) (shareware). It can assign different signatures and **From** names for each e-mail address on the same account. Setup is somehow cumbersome (after a [conversation with the dev](http://help.littleknownsoftware.com/index.php?pg=request), he acknowledged the plugin needs a redesign) but it works great, pretty much like standard e-mail identities. It also offers other features such as **Random Quotes** or **iTunes/Skype Statuses** on e-mail signatures.

Mail alone can't do what you (we) want. Even the option to insert signatures sequentially, when using multiple addresses separated by commas, in the **Accounts** pane, is as useful as the option to insert signatures randomly.