# Mail signatures--assigning to specific users

Tags: mail.app

Is it possible to assign a Mail signature to specific recipients? I want my signature to appear in emails I send to some people but not appear in emails I send to other people. Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty natural and useful need. It is provided by `Thunderbird` for example which is far ahead of `Mail` in the fields of the security, ease of use, ease of configurability.
<missing return here>
Try to send a feedback to Apple through:
`Mail > Provide Mail Feedback…` and if you receive a correct Feedback trust this function. Else, the name `Feedback` isn't appropriate and forget trust.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/95524/22003 .

Answer (score 2):

No. This isn't possible with a standard install of OSX Mail.app.

What you can do, as I am sure you are already well aware of, is set up multiple signatures, and manually select the signature that you desire to use. What you can do in the case of wanting no signature is set up a "signature" labeled "Empty", and then put nothing in there. Then have that set to default, or the other way around.